# redis cygwin running on local pc , connecting with redis-cli gives Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6668: Name or service not known

Tags: c, redis, window, cygwin

Getting :

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6668: Name or service not known
Aborted (core dumped)
```

the error is accored here in :
/dev/redis-5.0.7/deps/hiredis/net.c line 333

```
if ((rv = getaddrinfo(c->tcp.host, _port,  & hints,  & servinfo)) != 0) {

     hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;

     if ((rv = getaddrinfo(addr, _port,  & hints,  & servinfo)) != 0) {
         __redisSetError(c, REDIS_ERR_OTHER, gai_strerror(rv));  
        return REDIS_ERR;  
     }

 }
```

when i print hints im getting :

```
(gdb) print hints
$18 = {ai_flags = 0, ai_family = 23, ai_socktype = 1, ai_protocol = 0, ai_addrlen = 0, ai_canonname = 0x0, ai_addr = 0x0, ai_next = 0x0}
```

when i print rv im getting :

```
(gdb) print rv
$16 = 8
```

im using windows 10 64bit

is it somekind or ip6 problem ?

*UPDATE* 
i found the answer and compiled it using cygwin
https://github.com/meiry/redis5_compiled_for_windows10

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is a IP4. Is it the firewall allowing such self connections ?

Comment: found the answer : 
https://github.com/meiry/redis5_compiled_for_windows10